# Why does this MySQL query return so many results?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've been having trouble with a query joining 4 tables returning far too many results.  It's returning in the neighbourhood of 95 results, with some columns repeating 10 times where I figure it should only be 3, and with data that doesn't match up at all.

I started writing this post and figured I would code it up nicely on sqlfiddle for easier explanation, but when I ran the query there it returned results like what I want, with 34 results, and all data lines up where it should.  I'm wondering why the query works as I'd like it to there, and not on my server.  I see that they've added an 'extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort in the view execution link.  So what can I do to make this a clear result?  I'm trying to create a table displaying information about pricing.  I've included the query here for reference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    prices.sku,
    prices.base_price,
    prices.min_quantity,
    price_breaks.break_point,
    price_breaks.price,
    price_breaks.bonus,
    product_options.product_code,
    product_options.size,
    product_types.category_type,
    product_types.product_type_name
FROM prices
LEFT JOIN price_breaks ON price_breaks.sku = prices.sku
LEFT JOIN product_options ON product_options.sku = prices.sku
LEFT JOIN product_types ON product_options.product_code = product_types.product_code
WHERE prices.group = "a"
ORDER BY product_code ASC, sku ASC, break_point ASC
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67c14/1/0

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or more of your tables on right side of left joins must have multiple matching join rows.

Comment: Oh crap.  Of course.  The sku isn't unique.  Adding 

    AND price_breaks.group = prices.group 

completely fixed this.  I'm a dolt.  Thank you.